# Gstreamer RTP transmission of video + text

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, rtp

I am writing a gstreamer pipeline using command line syntax to send a video-stream and would like to send data with it. One solution I thought was feasible was to send the data as a subtitle file.

I can multiplex both video and subtitle files through rtp using the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtpmux name=mux ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 \ 
filesrc location=movie.avi ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! mux.sink_0 \
filesrc location=movie.srt ! subparse ! rtpgstpay ! mux.sink_1
```

I know it arrives as it should because I can view the port receiving the data with netcat. But when I try to read the stream with gstreamer on the receiver side I get "**syntax error**". The pipeline I am using now is

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp" ! rtpptdemux name=demux ! queue ! \
demux.src_0 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
demux.src_1 ! rtpgstdepay ! fakesink
```

In it, I try to undo every step took in the sender side, but something is off and I don't know what it is. (I would do something with the subtitles later, the fakesink is only there for debugging)

If there are other ways to do this I would gladly appreciate any help!

Regarding other possible solutions, I understand that RTP has support for text conversation using the rtp payload ([RFC 4103](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4103#section-5.1)) and for Timed Text ([RFC 4396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4396)) but from what I found at gstreamer plug-ins list for RTP, there is no support for it yet.

My end goal is to send a video from opencv in one computer along with some data and read it synchronously in the receiving end. After the command line works I would adapt it to opencv and continuously rewrite the subtitle  file or pass the variable directly.

Thanks so much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Command line syntax is incorrect because `queue` cannot come after `demux` element (although it seems somehow logical in command line).

In your case, `queue` element can be used after demux source pads. For example

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp" ! rtpptdemux name=demux \
demux.src_0 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
demux.src_1 ! queue ! rtpgstdepay ! fakesink
```

Comment: Thanks! IIt solved the syntax issue but other error appeared: /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data stream error. Funny that without the demux the video decoding works just fine.

Comment: @OnixCB try to remove only demux.src_1 branch and re-run command. Also try to set gstreamer debug level to higher values to see what is actual cause of data stream error.

Comment: I had tried that, but with no success. Good debugging info only appeared at level 4. Apparently, the demux.src_0 can't be created. It says "no such pad src_0 in element demux".

But it says in other line that "demux add pad ''src_96". Problably it means the payload size of the packet, not so sure. Switching the name of the demux for demux.src_96 in the pipeline doesn't work saying it is a "Internal data stream error." and further info says "stream does not contain enough data"