# Send synchronized data alongside video with gstreamer via upd (rtph264pay)

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I stream video from machine A to B using GStreamer:
x264enc -> rtph264pay -> udpsink

Every now and then I also need to transmit a few bytes of user data that need to be synchronized with the frames. I need help finding a way to do so.

I tried to find information on a few different approaches:

1. Add blobs to a frame: neither x264enc nor rtph264pay seem to offer an interface for this.
2. Encode data in subtitles: I don't know the data in advance as it is generated while the stream is running. I found this similar question without a solution: [Gstreamer RTP transmission of video + text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60553497/gstreamer-rtp-transmission-of-video-text)
3. Add chapters and encode data in chapter name: this doesn't seem to be implemented.
4. Are frames counted or do they include timestamps (generated by the sender) that the receiver may extract? Then I could use those to synchronize the times of the machines and just send the data separately and include the frame number or timestamp of that frame.

Thanks in advance!